# Hide all elements of a page except a specific div

Tags: html, css

I want to hide all the elements on the page, but only show the contents of `div.k1`. There are many more elements on the page. How do i do it in pure CSS?

```
<div>1-this will hidden</div>
<div class="k1">
  2-this div will displayed
  <p>3-this will displayed</p>
  <p>4-this div will displayed</p>
  <div>
    5-this will displayed
    <p>6-this will displayed</p>
    <div>
      7-this will displayed
      <p>8-this will displayed</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>9-this will hidden</div>
<div>10-this will hidden</div>

<div>1-this will hidden</div>
<div class="k1">
  2-this div will displayed
  <p>3-this will displayed</p>
  <p>4-this div will displayed</p>
  <div>
    5-this will displayed
    <p>6-this will displayed</p>
    <div>
      7-this will displayed
      <p>8-this will displayed</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>9-this will hidden</div>
<div>10-this will hidden</div> 11,12,13..
```

Comment: Select the top most divs that do not have this class and set display to none.

Comment: Why don't you add class (e.g: "hide") to the divs you want to hide , and hide them all together  `.hide{display:none}`?, instead of complex selectors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a crude way of doing this for divs nested up to 2 layers deep (as in your example). As you can see here, the problem is hiding all divs based on the tagName ('div'), unless they either have the className "k1" or are children of a div with that className. So we actually have to check at least 3 conditions before applying the hidden property. You can, of course, go deeper, if needed, by adding parentNode.parentNode.parentNode... and so on. But I would almost certainly approach this instead by assigning a class to the elements I want hidden, with an ID on the one I want to reveal. This is just a way of doing the job without changing any of your html.

```js
const allDivs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

for (let i = 0; i < allDivs.length; i++) {
  if(allDivs[i].className !== "k1" && allDivs[i].parentNode.className !== "k1"){
    if (allDivs[i].parentNode.parentNode.className !== "k1"){
      allDivs[i].hidden = true;
    }
  }
};
```

```html
<div class="k1">
    2-this div will displayed
    <p>3-this will displayed</p>
    <p>4-this div will displayed</p>
    <div>
        5-this will displayed
        <p>6-this will displayed</p>
        <div>
            7-this will displayed
            <p>8-this will displayed</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>9-this will hidden</div>
<div>10-this will hidden</div>
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

If all the elements you want to hide are `div`'s that are directly within the body you can do something like the following.

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll("body>div:not(.k1)");
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    items[i].style.display = 'none';
}
```

Basically what this does is select all the `div` elements that are directly within the body that do not have the class `k1`. Then it does a for loop on those items and sets each item to not display.

---

For a CSS solution you could just do something similar if the conditions are the same as I mentioned above.

```
body>div:not(.k1) {
    display: none;
}
```

---

If you are interested in learning more about CSS selectors I'd encourage you to take a look at the [W3 schools page](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) on it.

Comment: @Accountantم Fair enough. Just edited my answer. That same query selector should be possible in CSS as well.